# Opening file in emacs buffer when using vterm

Tags: term, find-file

My current workflow is often to do things in a terminal and open/change relevant files in a text editor.
Transitioning from VSCode to Emacs I am looking for a similar workflow that I got used to when using VSCode.
One of these things was navigating my directories in a VSCode terminal to search for the relevant file and simply opening it in the editor, i.e. `code file.txt`, and proceed to make changes.

I experienced a similar workflow using Emacs `term`, where I could simply navigate my folders and use `C-x C-f` (or rather `C-c C-f` when in the `term`-buffer) to open file as it defaulted to the current directory of `term`.
However, when trying out `vterm` as I needed a better terminal emulato, I found that `C-x C-f` does not default to the current directory in `vterm`.
This means that I have to manually navigate to the file I want to open in Emacs, which can be quite cumbersome.

Is there a way to configure `vterm` to export the current directory to the `find-file` functionality of Emacs? Or should I use `term` for simple directory navigation and `vterm` for more complex terminal emulation?

Comment: This sounds like you might want to enable `dirtrack-mode`. Alternatively, you can enable the emacs server, and then use `emacsclient <file>` from within vterm to edit files.

Comment: `dirtrack-mode` does not seem to work out of the box, but `emacsclient <file>` does appear to work!

Comment: Yes, `dirtrack-mode` only works with modes derived from `comint`, which `vterm` isn't. But I found a better option, which I'll add as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The README shipped with vterm describes how to do this in detail by
sending special escape sequences in your prompt.

Cribbed from there:

```bash
vterm_printf(){
    if [ -n "$TMUX" ] && ([ "${TERM%%-*}" = "tmux" ] || [ "${TERM%%-*}" = "screen" ] ); then
        # Tell tmux to pass the escape sequences through
        printf "\ePtmux;\e\e]%s\007\e\\" "$1"
    elif [ "${TERM%%-*}" = "screen" ]; then
        # GNU screen (screen, screen-256color, screen-256color-bce)
        printf "\eP\e]%s\007\e\\" "$1"
    else
        printf "\e]%s\e\\" "$1"
    fi
}

vterm_prompt_end(){
    vterm_printf "51;A$(whoami)@$(hostname):$(pwd)"
}
PS1=$PS1'\[$(vterm_prompt_end)\]'
```

Comment: This works great! It had never occurred to me that packages installed with `package-install` contain `README` files in the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/<package>` directory. This will undoubtedly be useful in the future.

Comment: Is there a way to do the vice versa? As in, I have an already running `vterm` process and want to open a `vterm` starting in same directory as my current buffer's?

Comment: @user129393192 I'm not sure I understand: `M-x vterm` switches to an existing vterm, `C-u M-x vterm` creates a new session in the same directory as the current buffer.